# ManualResetEvent with a BackgroundWorker : Current thread is busy while WaitOne()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, manualresetevent

Imagine following situation:

1. I got a signal on the ui thread from a third party server.
2. I start a BackgroundWorker with RunAsync to fetch data from a database and another async thread, which shall poll
   another hardware and receive signals, also not in ui thread
3. Inside the bg's  DoWork eventhandler I call manualresetEvent.Reset(). Then I call the data-fetching method, and then I call manualresetEvent.Set() and in the end I call the method METH_UI_1 on the ui thread by invoking it.
4. The other hardware thread shall receive hardware-data, which then itself is passed via Invoke to the ui into the ui thread to set some ui-elements periodically depending on the hardware-data I get.
5. The data from database can also not be fetched yet, but the ui must react to the hardware-data, which is polled by the second async thread.
6. In METH_UI_1 I call manualresetEvent.WaitOne();

Some times I get the exception, that the background worker is busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.

a) Is there really a need for a ManualResetEvent object ?

b) Would it be enough, to check for the isBusy property in order to issue WaitOne() only, when the background worker is no more busy ?

---

UPDATE: CODE.

MainForm.cs (event handler of third party hw-vendor, component, handled in ui thread)

```
 private void thrdptyPlcGotData(object sender, thrdptyPlcGotDataEventArgs e)
    {
        string strError = string.Empty;
        bool blNotReadyYet = false;            

        try
        {
            ThrdPtyPlcIfs.DataSetthrdptyPlc ds;

                ds = new ThrdPtyPlcIfs.Dataset();
                e.FillDataToTDataSet(ds);
               ThrdPtyPlcIfs.Statics.SaveDataSet(ds, CLStatics.FileName);


                               if (this.ValidateDsDetail(ds))
                                {
                                    // begin async work..... ask db, continue asking scale-> inside got weight of scale the rest is handled ( using or trashing db data )
                                    this.ExtractDataOfDataSet(ds);
                                    this.bgWorkerStart_Get_Data.RunWorkerAsync();                                        

                                    _oAsyncScaleManager.StartThread();
                                 }
         }
}
```

runworkerasynch does this:

```
private void bgWorkerStart_Get_Data_RFC_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            _blnStart_Get_Data_RFC = this.StartGetData_RFC(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogExcep(ex);
            _blnStart_Get_Data_RFC = false;
        }            
    }
```

WorkCompleted EventHandler of the BackGroundWorker:

```
 private void bgWorkerStart_Get_Data_RFC_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {  
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    this.ApplyDbDataToUi();
                }
                            );
            }
            else
            {
                this.ApplyDbDataToUi();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogAndShowExep(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code, my telepathy is not what it used to be.

Comment: Calling WaitOne() on the UI thread does **not** prevent the UI thread from pumping messages.  So won't prevent the "signal" from being received either.  Kaboom of course when the BGW didn't complete yet.  You could just create another BGW to avoid this.  Plenty of potential trouble lies ahead however.

Comment: @HansPassant - it doesnt?

Comment: It doesn't, blocking an STA thread is illegal.  The CLR pumps instead.  Just try it.

Comment: Why are there multiple message pumps ?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?  Just display a dialog for example.  Core issue is that you are trying to do something illegal and instead of cracking your knuckles with a ruler, the CLR does its best to do what you asked it to do.  Usually works just fine, until it doesn't.  Blocking the UI thread requires the same kind of courage as doing the exact opposite, calling DoEvents()

Comment: So can i just omit waitone? Or should I try again to assign to the event of bgw? Last tries did not fire it at all.

Comment: So, I decided to remove the ManualResetHandler and assigned to event RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: It did not help in any way. I still have the error. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

As rare as it might be , its possible the BackgrounWorker isn't finished when you set manualresetEvent inside the dowork method block.  If its at the very end , I would hook into the backgroundworker workcompleted event and set it in there.

Comment: I did that before. But the event never occurred. And the real problem seems like Hans Passant said. The data i am fetching from db varies from huge to very huge and m logfile seems to tell me about the crash really because of waitone. I added more loglines and will verify this tomorrow.

Comment: If the event never occurs you have something blocking it inside the "dowork" , like an endless loop.